# beginner, netmiko from bash awk sed question

Tags: python, sed, grep, paramiko, cisco

Greets.

I understand that python isn't shell.  I'm using this project as an excuse to get a boost into python though.  But I'm stuck.  Code is below, with embedded questions

If it matters I'm working in a jupyter notebook in python 3.something on centos7 and cisco 3650 switches.

```
import sys,re
import os
import io
import subprocess

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# trying to replicate this:
# ssh -q super@cisco1 "show ver" | grep -i "Cisco IOS Software" | sed -n     -e 's/^.*Version //p' | sed -n -e 's/\,.*//p'
# [output is, in this case] 
# 16.3.5b

platform = 'cisco_ios'
host = 'cisco1'
username = 'super'
password = 'sillypassword'

device= ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
out_version=device.send_command('show version')

# here's where I would do a 
#     grep -i "Cisco IOS Software" | sed -n     -e 's/^.*Version //p' | sed -n -e 's/\,.*//p'
# 
# However I understand that python doesn't 'pipe' like shell does so I need
# embedded loops (right?).  But I don't understand how to do 
# embedded loops with a stream of text that will be coming out 
# of the device.send_command, and then save -that- into the 
# variable out_version.

device.disconnect()
```

I've tried a number of approaches, popens, substrings, each increasingly uglier.  Even shelling out and writing a file with the result, then reading the output of the grep/sed pipe back in.  (that was ugly).  There's got to be a simpler way.  Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Thanks much.

Comment: What is your `out_version` like? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should look into the network-tools library which has a small set of command-line tools that use Netmiko. One of those tools is netmiko-grep. See here:

https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko-grep.html

Comment: Excellent!  thank you.  I actually resolved this particular problem by parsing the whole thing into a list, and then doing list processing:

Comment: Well, sorry, I was going to post the code snippet, but apparently not.  Thank you anyway.